# How to print H5 file to a text file?

Tags: python-2.7, hdf5

I can load H5 file in Python as follows.

```
import h5py

filename = 'brainwash_800000.h5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
```

I'd like to print all inside `f` to a text file. 
How can I do that?

EDIT:
I can print Keys as

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
filename = 'brainwash_800000.h5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
print(f.keys())
```

The outputs are

```
[u'conv1', u'conv2', u'forget_gate', u'inception_3a', u'inception_3b', u'inception_4a', u'inception_4b', u'inception_4c', u'inception_4d', u'inception_4e', u'inception_5a', u'inception_5b', u'input_gate', u'input_value', u'ip_bbox_unscaled0.p0', u'ip_bbox_unscaled0.p1', u'ip_bbox_unscaled1.p0', u'ip_bbox_unscaled1.p1', u'ip_bbox_unscaled2.p0', u'ip_bbox_unscaled2.p1', u'ip_bbox_unscaled3.p0', u'ip_bbox_unscaled3.p1', u'ip_bbox_unscaled4.p0', u'ip_bbox_unscaled4.p1', u'ip_conf0.p0', u'ip_conf0.p1', u'ip_conf1.p0', u'ip_conf1.p1', u'ip_conf2.p0', u'ip_conf2.p1', u'ip_conf3.p0', u'ip_conf3.p1', u'ip_conf4.p0', u'ip_conf4.p1', u'output_gate', u'post_fc7_conv.p0', u'post_fc7_conv.p1']
```

How to print these Keys and values in text file?

Comment: What exactly is in your h5 file? It would be perfect if you posted it here somehow.

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин Thanks I have updated in EDIT.

Comment: Please copy-paste the output of `h5ls brainwash_800000.h5` instead. It will provide more information already.

Answer (score 0):

How to dump a HDF5 file will depend on what's in the file.

For a single dataset, output to a format that can be input later to NumPy, for instance, would be done as

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
filename = 'brainwash_800000.h5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
np.savetxt('datafile.txt', f['dataset'][...])
f.close()
```

You can also use h5dump for that purpose, but it will produce comma separated values.

```
h5dump -d dataset -o brainwash_800000.txt -y brainwash_800000.h5
```

And you also lose the dimensions of the data. You can keep that information at the expense of having every line start by the data offset in N dimensions.

Comment: Thanks I have updated in EDIT. I don't have dataset so I have error. I checked my Keys in h5 file and how can I print these keys and data inside.